# converting varchar to date/Using isdate()

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a flat file that I am importing into a SQL Server 2005 staging table as character data.

I need to convert the birthday field to datetime format when copying it to the final destination table. I was doing so using the following:

```
BIRTHDAY = case when isdate(DOB)=1 then convert(datetime, '19'+right(DOB, 2)+left(DOB, 2)+substring(DOB,3,2)) else null end
```

The problem is only 100+ of the birthdays from the 32k+ file are identified as dates.

I cannot see a difference between the ones that are dates and the ones that aren't. I have included a sampling below.

```
good date   bad date
41129   100465
10531   122467
10429   20252
81030   62661
31231   20959
11028   91965
80928   60665
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the raw data is in MMDDYY, but the months are not 0-padded.

Building on this assumption, you can parse the date parts like below and rebuild a datetime:

```
declare @raw table (dob varchar(100));
insert into @raw
select '41129' union all   
select '10531' union all   
select '10429' union all   
select '81030' union all   
select '31231' union all   
select '11028' union all   
select '80928' union all   
select '100465' union all 
select '122467' union all 
select '20252' union all 
select '62661' union all 
select '20959' union all 
select '91965' union all 
select '60665'


select  *,
        [asDate] = dateadd(day, dd - 1, dateadd(month, mm - 1, dateadd(year, ('19' + yy)-1900, 0)))
from    (   select  dob,
                    substring(right('0' + dob, 6), 1, 2),
                    substring(right('0' + dob, 6), 3, 2),
                    substring(right('0' + dob, 6), 5, 2)
            from    @raw
        ) as stage (string, mm, dd, yy);
```